# Is there a way to create the Entity classes in Micronaut from an existing SQL database?

Tags: micronaut-data

I could not find any documentation on this topic. For example, I can create the model classes in Eclipse using the JPA plugin.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to create the Entity classes in Micronaut from an
> existing SQL database?

If you mean a tool that is part of Micronaut that will read your schema and generate source code for Micronaut entities, the answer is that there is no such capability provided by Micronaut.

Comment: Thanks for responding Jeff, is there anything outside of Micronaut

Comment: '...is there anything outside of Micronaut" - There is, but I do not have experience with them myself.  A google search turns up tools like http://www.telosys.org/.

Comment: Let me look that up thanks for responding, if I find something useful, would you want to add it your documentation somewhere?

Comment: @nimble "...if I find something useful, would you want to add it your documentation somewhere" - Of course.  It might be that a guide (https://micronaut.io/guides/) would be appropriate.  If you are interested in discussing contributing content we would love to speak with you. Please feel free to contact Micronaut Foundation Community Engagement Manager wiesej@objectcomputing.com.  I spoke with Jen this morning and she will be happy to coordinate with you.